# spring ntlmV2 not support

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, ntlm, jcifs

i know that JCIFS not support ntlm version2 , mean i cannot use spring-nltm to do ntlm2 . in that case, what library should I use with spring to do ntlm2?

ref: http://jcifs.samba.org/src/docs/ntlmhttpauth.html  (see blue line)

from info i get

> ```
> The NTLM HTTP Filter does not and can never support NTLMv2 as it uses a
> ```
>
> main-in-the-middle technique that is
>   broken by NTLMSSP's "target
>   information" used in computing
>   password hashes. However, the existing
>   Filter should continue to work.

**from http://jcifs.samba.org/ , it show jcifs-1.3.1 released / NTLM HTTP Filter Fixed  .  does that mean can use http filter with ntlmV2 without problem?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give [Waffle](http://waffle.codeplex.com/) a try. There is a "Spring-Security Negotiate (NTLM and Kerberos) Filter" and "Spring-Security Windows Authentication Manager". I have only used it's "generic Servlet Negotiate Security Filter", but that worked very good.

Comment: Waffle is only an option if your server is running Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You could give this Java NTLMv2 library a try:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/ntlmv2auth/

It's based on a JCIFS extension from the Liferay Portal project.